# Openbyurl -- one cell only

Tags: google-apps-script

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("data").getRange("p1:q2") 
var i = sheet.getValue()
```

Above commands are written in a scrip in the "home spreadsheet" to work on "target    spreadsheet -defined by the URL".

With above commands I can get value in the cell "p1" correctly only, whereas the other  cells p2,q1 and q2 in "p1:q2" were missing.

Subsequent commands revert to the "home spreadsheet".

My question is how to ensure "works are done on the target spreadsheet after OPENBYURL command -- which are known to be "not physically opened in my computer site" -- as the tutorial clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is not with `openByUrl()` but with the way you are getting values in a range.

When selecting more than a single cell you have to use `getValues()` which returns an array of cell values. See test code below

```
function test(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("data").getRange("p1:q2");
  var i = sheet.getValues();// getting a 2 D array
  for(var r=0;r<i.length;++r){
    for(var c=0;c<i[0].length;++c){
      Logger.log(i[r][c]);// get all values in the array p1, q1, p2, q2 in turn
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: On top of that what you are getting is a range not a sheet on the local 'sheet' variable. Leads to confussion.

Comment: Yes, Zig is right, try to choose variable names that are related to their nature to avoid confusion... I respected your choice in that demo code but it is quite confusing indeed :-)